# Is it possible to make iOS side bar views appear over the main screen instead of the main screen moving to the side?

Tags: ios

Currently, in ever iOS app I've seen that has side views accessed from the bar tabs or from swiping left or right, the main view moves left or right, "exposing" the underlying views.  Is it possible that when a user swipes left or right, the main view stays there but the side view drags over the main view?

Comment: show your codes before we could help.

Comment: maybe you should see the splitView on iPad, it's doing what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    - (IBAction)inputTileButton_TouchUpInside:(id)sender {


    if([inputTileButton isSelected]) {
        [Utility_Class AnimateViewToFrame:inputViewHiddenRect referenceView:rmHomeInputViewController.view];
        [inputTileButton setSelected:NO];
    }
    else {
        [Utility_Class AnimateViewToFrame:inputViewVisibleRect referenceView:rmHomeInputViewController.view];
        [inputTileButton setSelected:YES];
    }
}


+(void)AnimateViewToFrame:(CGRect)rect referenceView:(UIView *)view{

    if (!CGRectEqualToRect(view.frame,rect)) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:kANIMATION_DURATION animations:^{
            [view setFrame:rect];

        } completion:^(BOOL completion){

        }];
    }

}
```